# Remove ssh keys in github from command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, github

I'm creating a script in bash to install and configure all my workspace. How do I remove my ssh keys in github from command line?

I already search about and found this command, but this is specifically for deploy and not remove.

`curl -u 'user:password' --data '{"title":"My SSH","key":"'"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"'"}' https://api.github.com/user/keys`

The code above works perfectly but how do I remove (if exists) instead of deploy?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following request to get the list of installed keys:

```
curl -u 'user:password' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

And delete specific key by specifying its ID:

```
curl -u 'user:password' -X DELETE https://api.github.com/user/keys/:key_id
```

you can find documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#list-your-public-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Since [GitHub CLI gh 2.18.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.18.0), you can do:

```
gh ssh-key delete <id>
```

See [`gh ssh list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_ssh-key_list) for IDs (after authenticating yourself with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)).